# Multilist selecting the first selected value and storing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a multilist on my userform that the user can select up to three items on. I want to capture the first selected item and store it into a variable, pathology results, to be displayed on the next form. How do I store the first selected value from the list? Here is what I have that compares the values

```
If Me.OptCompare.Value = True Then 'storing value if the chooses to compare
    isFirst = False
        For i = 0 To Me.lstDiagnosis.ListCount - 1
            If isFirst = False Then
                If Me.lstDiagnosis.Selected(i) Then 
                   comp =  Me.lstDiagnosis.List(i, 0): isFirst = True       
                Else
                If Me.lstDiagnosis.Selected(i) Then  
                   comp = comp & " vs. " & Me.lstDiagnosis.List(i, 0) 
                End If
           End If
        Next
        Result = comp
        PathologyResults = "The pathology is the first selected, " & "."
End If
```

Comment: You haven't closed off  two of your if statements, could you add them in to the correct places

Comment: That `Else/If` needs to be on the same line as `ElseIf`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, one of the issues with your code is that your innermost `If` statements should either be written:

```vb
If Me.lstDiagnosis.Selected(i) Then 
   comp =  Me.lstDiagnosis.List(i, 0): isFirst = True
Else
    If Me.lstDiagnosis.Selected(i) Then  
       comp = comp & " vs. " & Me.lstDiagnosis.List(i, 0) 
    End If
End If
```

Or using `ElseIf`:

```vb
If Me.lstDiagnosis.Selected(i) Then 
   comp =  Me.lstDiagnosis.List(i, 0): isFirst = True
ElseIf Me.lstDiagnosis.Selected(i) Then  
   comp = comp & " vs. " & Me.lstDiagnosis.List(i, 0) 
End If
```

---

However, I would personally suggest the use of the `ItemsSelected` property so that you need only iterate over the items selected by the user as opposed to the entire dataset:

```vb
Dim var As Variant
Dim rtn As String

If OptCompare Then
    For Each var In lstDiagnosis.ItemsSelected
        rtn = rtn & " vs. " & lstDiagnosis.ItemData(var)
    Next var
    If rtn <> "" Then rtn = Mid(rtn, 6)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Variant Array.

```
Dim vR(), n As Integer
If Me.OptCompare.Value = True Then 'storing value if the chooses to compare
    For i = 0 To Me.lstDiagnosis.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lstDiagnosis.Selected(i) Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n) = Me.lstDiagnosis.List(i, 0)
        End If
    Next
    Result = Join(vR, " vs.")
    PathologyResults = vR(1) & "."
End If
```